# MongoDB Node.js aggregation too slow for function

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

i hope this question is not answered too many times.

However my problem is that i need to extract objects from an array inside a document.
The way i have solved this is with the aggregation pipeline builder integrated in MongoDB, with this i get the correct result.

But when i implemented this in the API i am building the data does not return with the request. So i suspect the operation is too slow or something along those lines.

My code looks like this:

```
const searchIngredientInInventory = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const dbConn = await getDb();

    const aggDoc = [
        {
          '$match': {
            'type': {
              '$ne': 'shoppingList'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$unwind': {
            'path': '$container'
          }
        }
      ]
    
    dbConn.collection(coll).aggregate(aggDoc).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(result);
            }
        })
}
```

And the database has this structure:

```
Cluster
  Database
    Collection
      Doc1
        Array with objects
      Doc2
        Array with objects
```

The collection is not large, its 5 documents and 36 kilobytes.

The return i get is empty array: `[]`

Does anybody have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing the correct collection name? I don't see a value declaration for "coll" in your code. Mongodb will not return an error if you specify a non-existent collection name, but will return an empty array

Comment: Ah i see, the collection name is a global constant so its declared above unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the aggregation document, or at least the problem stopped occurring when I updated it.

The new aggregation document looks like this now:

```
const aggDoc = [
    {
        '$match': {
            'type': {
                '$ne': 'shoppingList'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$container'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'item': '$container.item', 
            'expirationDate': '$container.expirationDate'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'item': {
                '$regex': ingredient
            }
        }
    }
]
```